# What to do with questions about unrevealed facts?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes we will get questions about facts that have not been revealed yet. Some of them will most likely not even be revealed. These questions will pop up again from time to time and remain unanswered until the fact is finally revealed if that even happens. What should we do with such questions? The question came up, when I was thinking of a question which I know is not revealed yet. Though relevant, should I refrain from asking, or ask anyway, leaving it open until it is finally revealed?

Some examples are listed below:

[Why didn't the Titans wipe out humanity yet?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18362/why-didnt-the-titans-wipe-out-humanity-yet)

[Why can't the birdcage be cut?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21737/why-cant-the-birdcage-be-cut)

[How was San-Juan Wolf put in the Impel Down?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19379/how-san-juan-wolf-was-put-in-impel-down)

Comment: To be honest, I remember reading this same question recently, but I can't seem to find it any more... Could someone please link this to the duplicate? Sorry about that :(